# Deployment Failure due Opportunity_hd Not Found Error

Tags: deployment

I received the following error while deployment

Opportunity_hd Not Found Error

[image: Images]

Whats causing this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the destination org did not had Historical Trending Available while source org had this Available .

To resolve this enable Historical Trending Manually in Destination org too.

Comment: Mohith - thanks for contributing this wisdom to the community!